# Optimization Problem with a skew-symmetric matrix as a variable

Tags: optimization, matrix-equations, lagrange-multiplier, skew-symmetric-matrices

I'm currently trying to solve the following optimization problem

$$\mathop{\text{minimize }}_{X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}} \left\| A X - B \right\|_F^2 \quad \text{ subject to  } X = -X^T$$

in which $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$ are row vectors. I tried some solvers in MATLAB for constrained linear least-squares problems, but I can never obtain a precise solution, only an approximated one. I also manually experimented with Lagrange multipliers, but still couldn't figure out a possible solution.

Is the problem well posed? Do you guys have any suggestion regarding any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectors will be typeset as rows, and matrices typeset as lists of rows.

**Theorem**.  As we vary $X$ over all skew-symmetric matrices, the smallest possible length for $E= AX-B$ is  $||E||= \frac{|A\cdot B}{||A||}$.

**Proof.** Use Gram-Schmidt to construct an orthonormal basis for space chosen so that your two given vectors $A$ and $B$  take the form $A=(a,0,0\ldots,0)$ and $B=(b_1,b_2,\ldots,0)$.  The structure of any skew-symmetric matrix is $ M=((0,s, 
\ldots);(-s,0,\ldots);(\ldots);\ldots)$ for some unknown scalar $s$. (The suppressed terms in this matrix  denoted by $\ldots$ have no effect in the computation that follows.)  Note that the row vector $A.M=(0, as, \ldots)$ and thus the  error vector  $E=A.M-B= (-b_1, as-b_2,\ldots)$. The length of this error vector  $E$ is minimized  when the suppressed terms $\ldots$ are zero, and when $s=b_2/a$; and with this choice the minimum length is $||E||= |b_1|=\frac{|A.B|}{||A||}$.

P.S. In general you can see that since always $AX \perp A$ (proof below), there is no hope that $AX$ can cancel out the component of $B$ that is parallel to $A$.

Proof. If $X$ is skew-symmetric, then $<AX, A>= <A, AX^t> =-<A,AX>=-<AX,A>$ so  $<AX,A>=0$; that is $AX\perp A$.

Comment: I also did think about something along these lines, however this still results in some degree of approximation, i.e. $||E||$ is non-zero. Is this the provably best way to solve the problem? Can the skew-symmetric matrix be chosen in a way that the norm of the error is closer to zero?

Comment: Proof is now imbedded in answer.

Comment: @FEDERICOBENZI Actually it is just a matter of euclidian geometry.
The elements $AX$ —where $X$ runs through the set of all skew matrices— is a (vector!) subspace $V\subsetneq\Bbb{R}^n$, and the minimum of the numbers $\Vert AX-B\Vert$ is nothing more than the distance from $B$ to $V$.
It is unique and, unless we have $B\in V$, it won't be 0.

Comment: @MathWonk I just check with my solver and the solution it provides is precisely the one you described in your proof. This was immensely helpful to me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathcal{M}_{1,n}(\mathbb{R})$, identified with $\mathbb{R}^n$, the usual scalar product is given by
$U\cdot V=U\mkern1mu{}^t\mkern-1mu V
=V\mkern1mu{}^t\mkern-1mu U$.
Let's put $a=\sqrt{A\mkern3mu{}^t\mkern-3mu A}=\Vert A\Vert$.
Also let's call $S$ the (real) vector space of all $n\times n$ antisymmetric matrices.
We show that, putting
$\color{red}{\frac1{a^2}(\mkern3mu{}^t\mkern-3mu AB-\mkern3mu{}^t\mkern-2mu BA)=X_0}\in S$, then
$\min\limits_{X\in S}\Vert AX-B\Vert^2=\Vert AX_0-B\Vert^2$.

**First** $AX_0=\frac1{a^2} (A\mkern3mu{}^t\mkern-3mu AB-A\mkern3mu{}^t\mkern-2mu BA)
=\frac1{a^2} (a^2B-(A\cdot B)A)
=B+\omega A$,
where $\omega$ is the real number $-\frac{A\cdot B}{a^2}\cdot$
**Second** let's observe that, if $H\in S$, then $A\perp AH$: we have
$$A\cdot(AH)=A\mkern3mu{}^t\mkern-2mu(AH)
=A\mkern3mu{}^t\mkern-2mu H\mkern3mu{}^t\mkern-3mu A
=A(-H)\mkern3mu{}^t\mkern-3mu A
=-AH\mkern3mu{}^t\mkern-3mu A
=-(AH)\cdot A
=-A\cdot(AH).$$
This quantity is thus 0.

Now let $X=X_0+H$ be any element of $S$ (so $H$ is antisymmetric); we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Vert AX-B\Vert^2&=&\Vert(AX_0-B)+AH\Vert^2\\
&=&\Vert\omega A + AH\Vert^2\\
&=&\omega^2\Vert A\Vert^2 + \Vert AH\Vert^2\quad \text{(by Pythagoras' theorem)}\\
&\geqslant&\omega^2\Vert A\Vert^2=\Vert AX_0-B\Vert^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
The expected minimum $\omega^2\Vert A\Vert^2=\frac{(A\cdot B)^2}{\Vert A\Vert^2}$ is thus attained at $X_0$, and also at every matrix $X$ such that $A(X-X_0)=0$ (they form an affine subspace of $S$).

P. S.: thanks to @MathWonk for detecting immediately a dreadful error in my first (deleted…) answer.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Let's use uppercase latin to denote matrices, lowercase latin for column vectors, and greek letters for scalars.
Using this convention the original problem variables become $(A,B)\to(a^T,b^T)$

Then for typing convenience, define the vector
$$\eqalign{
w &= X^Ta-b  \qif w^T = a^TX-b^T \\
}$$
Now write the objective function and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= w^Tw \\
d\phi &= 2w^Tdw = 2w^TdX^Ta \\
\grad{\phi}{X} &= 2aw^T \;=\; G \quad\big({\rm gradient}\big) \\
}$$
The constraint $X=\fracLR{X-X^T}2$ means that the constrained gradient is likewise skewed
$$\eqalign{
H &= \fracLR{G-G^T}2 \\
  &= aw^T-wa^T \\
  &= \LR{aa^TX - ab^T} - \LR{X^Taa^T - ba^T} \\
  &= \LR{aa^TX + Xaa^T} - \LR{ab^T - ba^T} \\
}$$
The zero-gradient condition $(H=0)\,$ yields
$$\eqalign{
aa^TX + Xaa^T = ab^T - ba^T \\
}$$
Note that the RHS is a skew matrix. Might $X$ be a scalar multiple of it?
$$\eqalign{
&X = \l\LR{ab^T-ba^T} \\
&\l aa^T\LR{ab^T-ba^T} + \l\LR{ab^T-ba^T}aa^T = \LR{ab^T - ba^T} \\
&\l\LR{a^Ta}\LR{ab^T-ba^T} = \LR{ab^T - ba^T} \qiq \l = \fracLR{1}{a^Ta} \\
}$$
Our ansatz was correct, therefore
$$X = \fracLR{ab^T-ba^T}{a^Ta}$$